# Have I been granted the visa or not?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, uk-citizens, tours

A couple of days ago, I received the following email from Home office(UK) for my spouse visa. I have deposited my IHS fee and it's been a week since I submitted my passport. Is there any chance where they can still refuse my visa? Additionally, how long would it take for them to return my passport?

> The decision to refuse your visa application has been overturned and
>   our office will now proceed to the next stage of your application. To
>   complete this process we require you to undertake the following steps:
>
> 1. Immigration Health Surcharge (IHS) payment needed On 6 April 2015, the UK Government introduced a Health Surcharge payment requirement
>      for non-EEA nationals who apply to come to the UK to work, study or
>      join family for a period of more than 6 months. Shortly, you will
>      receive a further email providing a link for your IHS payment. If you
>      do not receive an email within 7 working days of this email, please
>      contact IHS.Sheffield@fco.gov.uk with your name, GWF reference and
>      request the IHS payment email be sent. Want to find out more?
>
> To speak to someone about this, please visit:
>   https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi To find out more about IHS:
>   www.gov.uk/healthcare-immigration-application To find out about
>   refunds: https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration
>
> 2. Once you have received the IHS email and made your IHS payment, please take your passport along with a copy of this e mail to the visa
>      application centre where you initially made your application.
> 3. If you require a TB certificate for travel, please ensure you have this with your carry-on luggage, in order for you to present to the
>      Immigration authorities on arrival.
>
> To prevent any further delays with
>   processing your application, once you have made this IHS payment and
>   submitted your passport please send an e-mail to
>   IHS.Sheffield@fco.gov.uk containing your name, GWF reference, the
>   amount that you have paid for IHS and when you submitted your
>   passport.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> UK Decision Making Centre

Comment: After you made the IHS payment, did you send them an email with your particulars?

Comment: Yes, my lawyer in UK did.

Comment: I suggest you wait for 7 working days (not counting holidays/days off). And IHS is just to ensure that the applicant be able to use NHS; it does not guarantee issuing or rejection of the immigrant visa. To track the status, you can refer the visa application or ask your agent/lawyer to help you with it.